# trying to use MAMP's PHP, but `which php` always returns native OSX version?

Tags: php, macos, mamp, bash

I want to use MAMP on my OSX box as I am learning Laravel development.

I have added the following line to ~/.bash_profile:

```
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/bin:$PATH
```

I restarted terminal, restarted MAMP, but when I run `which php` the result is still `/usr/bin/php`.

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path can be changed, while the default OS response to the which command remains unchanged.

Example:

## which php

/usr/bin/php

## php

bash: Applications/MAMP/bin/php: No such file or directory

Run this command:

## echo "$PATH"

[NOT a complete answer]